# How do I find the $x$ intercepts for $-x^2-3x+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the $x$ intercepts? $-x^2-3x+3$?

I converted the function into vertex form but I am stuck at $3/4= -(x^2+1.5)$.
Can someone give me and idea what I can do?

Comment: I think you made a mistake with your arithmetic.

Comment: One of the problems you'd run into is that you lost track of the negative sign on the quadratic term.  Your "completion of squares" should be $$ \ -(x^2 + 3x \ \ ) + 3 \ = \ -(x^2 + 3x + \frac{9}{4} \ \ ) + 3 + \frac{9}{4} \ = \ \ -(x + \frac{3}{2})^2 +  \frac{21}{4} \ , $$ since you are really _subtracting_ $ \ \frac{9}{4} \ $ by having it inside the negative term.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a function $y = -x^2-3x+3$. Along the $x$-axis, $y=0$, right?  So set $y=0$ and solve for $x$.  Hint: Quadratic formula.

Comment: Beat me by six seconds! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x$-intercepts occur at $y=0$, i.e., $-x^2-3x+3=0$. Use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can complete the square.

$x^2 + 3x - 3 = (x + \frac{3}{2})^2 - 3 - \frac{9}{4} = 0$. So, $(x + \frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{21}{4} \Rightarrow x = -\frac{3}{2} \pm \frac {\sqrt{21}}2.$

Thus the x-intercepts are $(\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2},0)$  and $(\frac{-3-\sqrt{21}}{2},0)$.

Comment: Be sure not to give the full answer if it's the HW question; other than that, good answer you have.

Comment: Notice that what the result from the quadratic formula shows is that the $ \ x-$ coordinate of the vertex is midway between the $ \ x-$ intercepts.  This is useful to keep in mind in solving certain sorts of problems.  (Completing the square in this way _is_ where the formula comes from...)